# Send Ctrl-C to piped command

Tags: command-line

Using a command like:

```
tcpdump -w - | bzip2 -c > capture.cap.bz2
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the `tcpdump` command, I end up with a broken bzip2 archive (I'm assuming because I've terminated both processes).

I know I can send  `` kill `pidof tcpdump` ``, but I would like to be able to stop this without opening another SSH connection.

Is there a way to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> only to one of the subprocesses (`tcpdump` in this case)?

Comment: Assuming `bash` : CTRL+z first, then kill ...   *(CTRL+z suspends the job, pick it out again with `fg` - check `job control` in `man bash`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could suspend, `bg`, and kill the process in the same ssh connection, a better solution might be using the built-in compression functionality of tcpdump.

Use the built-in **-z** option for tcpdump rather than piping to bzip.  This will only compress (and save) complete sections (rotations).

> **-z** *postrotate-command*
>
> Used in conjunction with the **-C** or **-G** options, this will make tcpdump run " *postrotate-command file* " where file is
> the savefile being closed after each rotation. For example, specifying
> **-z gzip** or **-z bzip2** will compress each savefile using gzip or bzip2.

**Source:** http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html

Comment: Nice to know. I had not tought about using `bg`! About the -z option, I need the compression to be made in memory, I'm exaclty trying to avoid writes to the disk.

Comment: The redirection writes to the disk: `> capture.cap.bz2`

Comment: But it will write considerably less times and bytes! :)

Answer (score 0):

The full command based on @Steven's suggestion will be:

```
tcpdump -w capture_file -z bzip2
```

Then killing tcpdump won't leave a corrupted zip file. The alternate is of course using Ctrl-Z, fg and bg to accomplish something similar.

I hadn't noticed the -z option until I saw @Steven's suggestion.